# How do I fix "git-svn died of signal 6" during clone?

Tags: git-svn, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to clone a new SVN repository with little more than trunk/branches/tags in it, but it fails with relatively little information:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout https://mydomain.com/svn/myrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/datguy/myrepo/.git/
Authentication realm: <https://mydomain.com> (null)
Password for 'datguy': 
error: git-svn died of signal 6
```

I thought I was using the default versions of git & svn that came with OSX 10.8.3, but I noticed that the svn version reported by the following two commands was different:

```
$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33) (svn 1.6.18)

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
```

I apparently installed a newer version of svn with homebrew (in `/usr/local/bin/svn`). I am able to work with this repository using svn, including import, checkout, etc.  How do I figure out what's going wrong with git-svn, or update the svn bindings?

**EDIT** - I dug into the console and found this perl crash report.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience reading these reports to know what it's trying to tell me.

```
Process:         perl5.12 [13309]
Path:            /usr/bin/perl5.12
Identifier:      perl5.12
Version:         77.2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  git [13308]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Ra/_Ra.bundle
PlugIn Identifier: _Ra.bundle
PlugIn Version:    ??? (52)

Date/Time:       2013-04-18 15:20:16.512 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
__abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff977d0d46 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff968b6ec0 __abort + 193
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9687877d __chk_fail + 35
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff968787f0 __memset_chk + 41
4   libneon.27.dylib                0x000000010e0b2cf1 ne__ntlm_authenticate + 1018
5   libneon.27.dylib                0x000000010e0b1455 ntlm_challenge + 171
6   libneon.27.dylib                0x000000010e0afd17 ah_post_send + 1400
7   libneon.27.dylib                0x000000010e0a8a10 ne_end_request + 100
8   libneon.27.dylib                0x000000010e0a8bbc ne_request_dispatch + 70
9   libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.0.0.dylib    0x000000010e0729fd svn_ra_neon__request_dispatch + 404
10  libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.0.0.dylib    0x000000010e06d357 svn_ra_neon__exchange_capabilities + 186
11  libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.0.0.dylib    0x000000010e071156 0x10e063000 + 57686
12  libsvn_ra-1.0.0.0.dylib         0x000000010df4d096 svn_ra_open3 + 1170
13  libsvn_ra-1.0.0.0.dylib         0x000000010df4c483 svn_ra_open + 175
14  _Ra.bundle                      0x000000010e0db65b _wrap_svn_ra_open + 675
15  libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dc36abd Perl_pp_entersub + 2456
16  libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dc2eee1 Perl_runops_standard + 38
17  libperl.dylib                   0x000000010dbdff26 perl_run + 453
18  perl5.12                        0x000000010dbc5d54 main + 221
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9685b7e1 start + 1
```

Comment: I believe `signal 6` means `ABRT` (abort)

Comment: what is causing it to abort?

Comment: I don't know really, perhaps you could check your systems log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16115883/980607), I learned how to update the `SVN::Core` perl module.  After doing that, I was able to clone the svn repository.