# How do I update the perl subversion bindings on OSX?

Tags: perl, git-svn, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091953/what-does-git-svn-died-of-signal-6-mean-during-clone-operation) with git-svn that may be related to the perl svn bindings.  Even after installing new versions of subversion and git using homebrew, git-svn is using an old version of svn:

```
$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.8.2.1 (svn 1.6.18)

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
```

How do I make git-svn use the newer version of svn?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341159/how-to-upgrade-the-svn-version-used-by-git-svn (use macports)

Comment: MacPorts is not the answer, but the link helped.  I'll post my answer below.  Recommending MacPorts to solve a Homebrew problem is like recommending yum/rpm to solve a problem with apt.  MacPorts has overhead that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342029/980607), I found a reasonable solution.  I ran `sudo cpan SVN::Core`, which updated the svn version of git-svn:

```
$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.8.2.1 (svn 1.7.3)
```

The native svn version was unchanged.  So I'm left with two different versions of svn, but at least they are the same major version.

Answer (score 1):

If using homebrew, uninstall git, update/install svn with homebrew, then reinstall git with:

```
brew install git --with-brewed-svn
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to point the svn-perl binding to a specific svn installation on your system would be to add following line to the bash profile:

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/svn-perl
```

The path will vary depending on the installation directory of svn-perl bindings. For e.g., WanDisco svn client installation is usually under `/opt/subversion/lib/svn-perl`.

I learned about this trick from [here](http://jfcouture.com/2007/12/16/installing-git-on-mac-os-x/).