# How do I use git svn on Big sur

Tags: git, svn

Error occurs when I call `git svn clone`.
I know what 'flat namespace' means, bug how can I update SVN to fix this problem?

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _svn_ra_make_callbacks
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Ra/_Ra.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _svn_ra_make_callbacks
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Ra/_Ra.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

error: git-svn died of signal 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Run `sudo cpan SVN::Core` to update the svn version of git-svn.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115883/how-do-i-update-the-perl-subversion-bindings-on-osx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. But not work for me. Error: The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.